# Move to Health SE custom offtopic

Tags: feature-request

Now that the [Health SE](https://health.stackexchange.com/) has opened, it seems that there is a good reason for questions to be moved there, since as far as I can tell there are a large number of questions here that get closed for the reason of being health questions.

Will it be possible to add a custom move to Health SE, alternatively, a custom off topic reason when voting to close can be useful too.

Comment: Really nice idea!

Comment: I'm amazed that got off the ground!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Health is a very early beta site, those never get a migration path. A new site should find their scope on their own, older sites pushing questions to a new site can be problematic.

Migration paths are in general only established between graduated sites, and only if there is a clear need for them.

Comment: What about the offtopic then? There is already one for General Chemistry, can we add that?

Answer (score 4):

Just to add my 2-cents worth: [Health.SE](https://health.stackexchange.com/) has a very premature appearance with a lot of specific self-help questions of wildly varying quality. I would not easily encourage folks to post their questions there if they seek scientific input. Biology.SE is definitely more mature.